# WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in Prolog on JBoss only

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, basic-authentication

The error I am getting are in a few forum posts, but all the scenarios seem slightly different than mine.

I am writing a JAX-WS web service client to communicate to a soap-based web service that uses basic authentication (http level only). I generated the client using wsimport on the wsdl.

**There are two versions of the web service available to me for testing:**

- Port 8080 - no authentication
- Port 80 - requires basic http level authentication

**What the web service does:**

- This is just a simple web service that lets me send an base64 encoded xml payload into it.

**I verified the following:**

- I can correctly send both web services (80/8080) using SOAPUI from my localhost
- I can correctly send both web services using a test JAVA application from my localhost

**What fails:**

- As soon as I try to deploy my web service client as a .war on jboss5.1... only the port 8080 web service works. When I try the web service on port 80, I get this error.

*10:36:51,467 ERROR [CommonClient] Exception caught while (preparing for) performing the invocation: 
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.getSOAPFaultException(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:84)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.binding.SOAP11BindingJAXWS.throwFaultException(SOAP11BindingJAXWS.java:107)*

**The Core Code for my test client:**

```
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);   
        ImportLoan port = service.getPort(ImportLoan.class);
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,  properties.getProperty("username"));
        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,  properties.getProperty("password"));
        ImportLoanRequestType requestType = new ImportLoanRequestType();
        requestType.setData(strEncodedPayload);
        ImportLoanResponseType responseType = port.importLoanApp(requestType);
```

**What I'm Hoping For**

I just need some ideas to triage here. I assume I am getting some invalid SOAP response back that cannot be parsed correctly. I just find it odd that it only happens when sending the service from JBoss (my app server), so it must be something on my end. SOAPUI works fine. The exact same code written in a standalone test.java file works fine as well.

**Update... later in the evening**
Of course I would find the answer the same day I ended up posting the question. I watched the http traffic and realized the HTTP500 error response (with the soap eof prolog error) came back after half the data was sent. Apparently JBoss chunks the data. That worked fine against the 8080 service, but the port 80 service didn't support chunking for some reason. I assumed it was an authentication error, but appears to be that the web service doesn't support chunking. I modified the standard-jaxws-client-config.xml (jbossws.deployer/META-INF folder) on my server. Set the chunksize from 2048 to 0, and voila... problem solved. Hope this helps somebody else out there someday.